# ES6 arrow functions

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

I have a problem with understanding ES6 arrow function syntax. Why this code does not work:

```
Meteor.publish('parties', (options, searchString) => {
...
})
```

But this one works:

```
Meteor.publish('parties', function (options, searchString) {
...
})
```

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error?  It looks syntactically fine.

Comment: @TbWill4321 no error. Just does not work.

Comment: @TbWill4321 Receiving this error on server side Exception from sub parties id WHLG4KoSdkGm5RzcH TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'added'

Comment: You should read about what happens to the value of `this` when you use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Ah. The perils of libraries that mess with the scope for the nicety of being able to refer to something library-related with the `this` keyword from your callback. IMO, this was never a good idea (jQuery, I'm looking at you)

Comment: Again, how can someone learn about arrow functions without learning how `this` works inside arrow functions?

Comment: @FelixKling For me and for those who wants to learn about this I'd recommend reading: https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/ and https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary difference between example one and example two is that example one uses the calls scope while example two uses Meteors scope. If I had to make a guess it would be that it is not working because you are using `this` and expecting a different scope. Here is a quick example to demonstrate this functionality...

```
(function () {
    var Example = (function () {
        function Example() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log(this); //this === window
            }, 0);

            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(this); //this === test
            }, 0);
        }        
        return Example;
    }());

    var test = new Example();
}());
```

You can read about the specifics [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this)

Comment: Ah yes, lexical scoping in ES6